# remove <BR> from html when it's opened in text file

Tags: c#, html

I have a data like this

```
*******************[MESSAGES OF MASTER JOB]*******************<BR><BR><BR><BR>
CA ARCserve Backup -- Backup<BR><BR><BR><BR>
[SubJob]<BR><BR><BR><BR>
Totals For................... SubJob 1<BR><BR>    
Job No....................... 18<BR><BR>
Job ID....................... 8786<BR><BR>
Total Session(s)............. 8<BR><BR>
Total Size (Disk)............ 512.12 GB<BR><BR>
Total Size (Media)........... 514.29 GB<BR><BR>
Elapsed Time................. 4h 30m 54s<BR><BR>
Average Throughput........... 1.91 GB/min<BR><BR>
SubJob Status................ Finished<BR><BR><BR><BR>
```

That data is from HTML and I opened in text file.. my problem is I want to remove 
 and replace it to a new line so I can read that data in notepad like I read that data in web but my code is not working.. How can I replace them?

Here is my code

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
string x;
string[] wards = {"<BR>", "<br>"};
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
    using(System.IO.StreamReader txttemp = read)
    {
        x = txttemp.ReadLine();
        foreach (string ward in wards)
        {
            if (x.Contains("<br>")|| x.Contains("<BR>"))
            {
                ward.Replace("<BR>", Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ooh thanks.. it's is my first time ask question @circl

Comment: The data in your file contain `<br>`?

Comment: yup.. that is the data when i open in web browser.. but when i open in notepad, the line break become <BR> and i want remove them so when i open in notepad, it's same like i open in browser @null

Comment: Make text-file better visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, When you are using Replace() it return a modified string instead of just edit the target so It should be

```
ward = ward.Replace("<BR>", Environment.NewLine);
```

However, you are not supposed to edit element during the loop.
So my suggestion is

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] yourHtmlInRows = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
    List<string> resultYouWant = yourHtmlInRows.Select(str => 
        str.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine)
        .Replace("<BR>", Environment.NewLine)).ToList();
    File.WriteAllLines(ofd.FileName, resultYouWant);
}
```

Comment: are you mean like this?
`if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{ StreamReader read = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
 using (System.IO.StreamReader txttemp = read) 
{ x = txttemp.ReadLine(); 
var resultYouWant = wards.Select(str => str.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine).Replace("<BR>", Environment.NewLine)).ToList(); } 
}`

Comment: I didn't review all of your code before. There was one extra problem that you are trying to replace `ward`. But, the content you read was in `x`. In short, I updated my answer see if it works for you. And try not to use `x` as a variable name when it can be meaningful.

Comment: i still can't replace the data and my code is only that  @circle

Comment: You mean you can't replace it in the program or It didn't effect the file?

Comment: it didn't effect the file.. i want to remove <BR> from my text file so i can read that like i read in browser

Comment: You need to write your modification back to the file by `File.WriteAllLines()` or something like it. Answer updated.

Comment: You welcome and you can press the empty check left side of my answer to accept it.

Comment: ooh oke.. sorry.. it's my first time ask in here @circle

Comment: No problem and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you as well